# Unity3D SteamVR Tutorial Vive Pro Source Code

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive, steamvr

I want to write application on Unity for Vive Pro and it is very similar with the application of steamvr tutorial which has a ball robot character.
Where can I get this source code?

Answer (score 1):

If you check SteamVR’s scripts in the hierarchy, you should be able to find it:

`*assets/steamvr/interactionsystem/samples/joejeff/*`

There are multiple C# scripts like: `*JoeJeffController.cs*`, `*JoeJeffGestures.cs*` etc

I hope this answers your question!